# How to return a int pointer, pointed to the start of vector<int>

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I think I should describe this question in a detailed way.

```
class solution{
public:
  int* function(int para){
   //clear ret
   ret.clear();
   //some lines to manipulate the ret;
   //...........
   return ret.data();
  }
private:
 std::vector<int> ret;
}
```

I HATE to use pointer like this as well. But the design requirement speficed to use int* to as return. so, will this approach guarantee the function return pointer useable?

Comment: [`vec.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

Comment: @Borgleader undefined return value in this case

Comment: If you're returning a pointer to the first element in the `vec` you will get undefined behaviour because `vec` is passed by value and will be destroyed at the end of the function.

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes but that would happen no matter with the way he's got it setup right now (the explanation of why would require a full answer). I'm merely pointing out he can call vector's data member function instead of writing his own function.

Comment: You should take care when you use a pointer to the data, because when the vector is manipulated (elements are pushed or removed form it) then the address where the data is stored may change.

Comment: @t.niese not if elements are removed, just if new ones are inserted and the capacity is exceeded and the vector object fails to reallocate the buffer (because somebody else already allocated infront of the vectors internal buffer)

Comment: @user2840454 Your change makes no difference, if vec is inside body of your function, or outside. If you really want it inside your function, make it static or global.

Comment: @Paranaix When the size of the vector decreases under a certain limit the vector will decrease the allocated memory. Is it guaranteed that when the size of the allocated memory is decreased that the memory address is retained? While it is logical that the system does not need to move the memory on decrease, I thought it is up to the system if the memory moved.

Comment: Your edit made answers below (kind of) obsolete -1

Comment: @user2840454 answer to version with solution class, yes - but under condition you solution object will not be destroyed for the duration returned  pointer will be used.

Answer (score 3):

```
// NOT: int* function(std::vector<int> vec){
int* function(std::vector<int>& vec){ // see & here
    if(vec.empty()){
        return nullptr; // nullptr is more meaningful for pointers
    }
    return vec.data();
    // OR: return &vec.front();
}
// On each update of the vector&, update the pointer also
// as the memory location MAY change.
// And obviously, the vector& must outlive the pointer.
```

**You need a reference&.** You can't return a valid pointer to a temporary local variable like your argument is.

Comment: If it is my defined class, can I save the input vec into my own private vec, then use return vec.data() ?

Comment: @user2840454 **The vector variable must live as long as you need to use the pointer. And if you resize it, update the pointer as it MAY move.** --- This is the rule, make it work in your design.

Answer (score 1):

You have a general problem here:

```
int* function(std::vector<int> vec){

}
```

If you pass a vector to this function a local copy is constructed only available during the function call (as thats its scope), as soon as your function returns, the vector becomes destructed and the possible returned pointer thus invalidated. To fix this we have to pass by reference:

```
int* function(std::vector<int>& vec)
```

We can now acquire the pointer by:

```
return vec.data();
```

---

But notice that this function is pretty senseless, as you can simply call the method (`data()`) on your vector directly instead of passing it into a function.

Answer (score 0):

In such a function `int* function(std::vector<int> vec)` you're passing the parameter by value, thus when calling `function(my_vector)` the compiler will create a copy of `my_vector` by calling the copy constructor and this copy will live ONLY between the moment the program control flow enter your function and the moment the control flow exit your function.

So you cannot, in that context return a pointer to the beginning of your vector, because it will not exists any more when you're exiting that function. This is call "returning a temporary" and this is seriously bad because your program can crash when accessing this pointer.

To do what you want you can pass your vector by reference: `int* function(std::vector<int>& vec)` and then call `vec.data()`:

```
int* function(std::vector<int>& vec)
{
   return vec.data();
}
```

But please, if you can, work with `std::vector` and don't mess with pointers.

Comment: **OP**: *Take this last sentence as good advice.* If you are asking this question, you are not ready to use raw pointers yet.